# Странности с авторизацией

Tags: php, javascript, auth

Авторизация проходит, но только после того, как я неправильно что-то ввиду. Пока не увижу сообщение об ошибке авторизация не проходит. Точнее, он обновляется, но мое подобие на профиль не появляется

```
$("#button-auth").click(function() {

    var auth_email = $("#auth_email").val();
    var auth_pass  = $("#auth_pass").val();

    if (auth_email == "" || auth_email.length > 30) {
        $("#auth_email").css("borderColor", "#FDB6B6");
        send_email = 'no';
    } else {
        $("#auth_email").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
        send_email = 'yes';
    }

    if (auth_pass == "" || auth_pass.length > 15) {
        $("#auth_pass").css("borderColor", "#FDB6B6");
        send_pass = 'no';
    } else {
        $("#auth_pass").css("borderColor", "#DBDBDB");
        send_pass = 'yes';
    }

    if ($("#rememberme").prop('checked')) {
        auth_rememberme = 'yes';
    } else {
        auth_rememberme = 'no';
    }

    if (send_email == 'yes' && send_pass == 'yes') {
        $("#button-auth").hide();
        $(".auth-loading").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/include/auth.php",
            data: "email=" + auth_email + "&pass=" + auth_pass + "&rememberme=" + auth_rememberme,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes_auth') {
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $("#message-auth").slideDown(400);
                    $(".auth-loading").hide();
                    $("#button-auth").show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Код авторизации:

```
<?php 
    if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'yes_auth') {
        echo '<p id="auth-user-info"><img src="img/user.png">Здравствуйте, ' . $_SESSION['auth_name'] . '!</p>';    
    } else {
        echo '<ul class="top">
                  <li class="main"><a href="registration.php">Регистрация</li></a>
                  <li class="main"><a class="top-auth">Вход</a></li>
              </ul>';    
    }
?>

<div id="block-top-auth">
  <div class="corner"></div>

  <form method="POST">
    <ul id="input-email-pass">
      <p id="message-auth">Неверный email и(или) Пароль</p>

      <li><input type="text" id="auth_email" placeholder="E-mail"></li>
      <li><input type="password" id="auth_pass" placeholder="Пароль"></li>

      <ul id="list-auth">
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme"><label for="rememberme">Запомнить меня</label></li>
        <li><a id="remindpass" href="#">Забыли пароль?</a></li>
      </ul>

      <p id="button-auth"><a>Вход</a></p>
      <p class="auth-loading"><img src="img/loading.gif" width="55px" height="55px"></p>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

function(data) возвращает:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM reg_user WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'");
If (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'yes_auth'; 
    $_SESSION['auth_pass'] = $row["pass"];
    $_SESSION['auth_email'] = $row["email"];
    $_SESSION['auth_name'] = $row["name"];

    echo 'yes_auth';

}else
{
    echo 'no_auth';
}  
}
```

Comment: Раз уж так, то приложите код php самой авторизации (справа внизу кнопка *править*), пожалуйста.

Comment: Можете смотреть

Comment: Что Вам возвращает `data` в `success: function(data) {...`?

Comment: снова обновил,смотрите внизу.